# I need some help to identify this component

Tags: pcb, components, datasheet, hard-drive, information

[image: I found this component on PCB of a hard disk drive]

I require assistance in locating this component, which bears the designation EK 67, as evident in the accompanying image. The challenge lies in my inability to procure its datasheet, thereby impeding my understanding of the component's nature and hindering my replacement efforts. To assess the situation, must subject it to testing since the thermal camera indicates excessive heating, and it is imperative for me to determine if this is within the normal range. This particular component is situated on a PCB of a hard disk drive.
Regrettably, I am unsure of the procedure for including two photos to showcase the complete card, but I have enclosed an image displaying the appearance of the component. I express my sincere gratitude in advance and hope for your valuable assistance.

[image: This is the full PCB]

I managed to find a way to attach two photos, and here is the complete board of the hard disk drive. I have highlighted the component I am looking for with a yellow circle, which can be seen more clearly in the first photo. I greatly appreciate your assistance and apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: What leads you to believe it needs replacement?

Comment: The component was overheating.

Comment: Given its role, I’d guess your problem is downstream of it. Do you have access to a thermal camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [MPS MP5016](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/277/MP5016GQH_Z-2946275.pdf) current limit switch.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. Could I ask you how you manage to find these types of components when you don't have much information or nomenclature? I struggle a lot with it; I couldn't figure out what it was.

Comment: @EEIR There is no general method, it depends on the information that are available. In this case the package is not that common, so this is what I searched for after the markings didn't yield good results.